# Code to parse text within files slows to a halt c#

Tags: c#, regex, file-io, profiling

```
 private static void BuildDictionaryOfRequires(Regex exp, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary, DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        var i = 0;
        var total = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                                 Where(x => x.Extension == ".aspx" || x.Extension == ".ascx").Count();
        foreach (var item in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                                 Where(x => x.Extension == ".aspx" || x.Extension == ".ascx"))
        {
 #if DEBUG
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
 #endif

            var text = File.ReadAllText(item.FullName);

            MatchCollection matches = exp.Matches(text);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var matchValue = match.Groups[0].Value;

                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(matchValue))
                {
                    dictionary[matchValue] = string.Format("{0},{1}", dictionary[matchValue], item.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    dictionary.Add(matchValue, item.Name);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found matches in {0}.", item.Name));

 #if DEBUG
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time used (float): {0} ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
 #endif


            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} of {1}", (++i).ToString(), total));
        }
    }
```

there are about 232 files the lambda finds. It rips through 160 just fine then comes to a crawl. I'm profiling the code now but wondering if there is anything obvious i'm doing wrong.

the regex is

```
    Regex exp = new Regex(@"dojo\.require\([""'][\w\.]+['""]\);?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

all of the files are similar length and similar structure.

most files take less than 30ms but some are 11251 ms.

with updated regex the whole process takes 1700ms now. phew!

Comment: Close and Dispose are NOT equivalent, usually Dispose also calls close, like for SqlConnection, but this does not mean they are equivalent because a Close never Disposes (or at least usually does not).

Comment: @Davide I added those for fun after noticing the perf hit. I can probably remove those lines because of the using statement. I will have to check the files vcsjones and see if I can notice something.

Comment: @Davide: from MSDN on StreamReader.Close: "This implementation of Close calls the Dispose method passing a true value."

Comment: Please define "comes to a crawl". Is it that the processing gets progressively slower with each file, or is it that File 160 is as fast as File 1 but File 161 never finishes?

Comment: @Michael files 0-168 complete in under 20ms each then there's a 11190ms the a 1.5 ms then a 7ms then the next one takes a very long time. so no it is not progressive.

Comment: When it slows to a crawl, just hit the pause button on the IDE. You'll see exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simplifying your regex:

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"dojo\.require\([""'][\w\.]+[""']\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

**UPDATE**: Then remove the semi-colon at the end if you want to match your example.

Comment: actually it does match. just realized i don't always have a ; since js doesn't require it so adding ;? fixed that.

Comment: @Steve Yeah, the `;?` should mostly fix your performance gain all by itself. Since you would only get the hit on the performance when the original regex with the non-optional `;` failed.

Comment: @JacobEggers so the ;? will ruin the goods? Is there a better option?

Answer (score 2):

I think the current offending piece is piece of the regex here:

```
(\w+\.?)*
```

Remove the ? and add `\w*` and you'll match all of the same strings, but much more efficiently.

`(\w+\.?)*` can match `asdf` many different ways:

- asdf
- asd,f
- as,d,f
- a,s,d,f
- a,sd,f
- a,s,df
- a,sdf
- as,df

I'm guessing that some of your files had a bunch of lines like this:

```
dojo.require('asdf')  //with no ;
```

Your regex would fail the greediest match, and then try every other combination until it eventually didn't get any match at all. This can get very expensive as the `'asdf'` string grows.

Try using:

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"dojo\.require\((\""|\')((\w+\.)*\w*)(\""|\')\);");
```

Comment: I would also suggest the use of `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`, since none of the groups in the Regex are referenced.

Comment: that doesn't match dojo.require('dijit.form.Button');
        dojo.require('dijit.form');
        dojo.require('ijit.widgets.upload.FileUpload')

Comment: @Michael that sped things up a bit. Still hitting the same perf bumps though. Wonder if it has to do with the encoding of the files perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelPetito the explicitcapture part, can you provide the full change to the regex so I can see how it matches my test case?

Comment: @Steve: I provided the full regex as a separate answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. take out the DiscardBufferedData call.  You don't need it, and
   it's expensive.
2. Fix the double dispose.  Note that Close also
   calls Dispose, so you can get rid of that as well.
3. Actually, there is a
   File.ReadAllText method that can be used to get rid of the
   StreamReaders you are constructing and disposing of.

Comment: removed those calls, and switched to File.ReadAllText - this gave a huge performance gain. STill slowing way down on some relatively non complex files. It has to be something with the regex i must presume?

Comment: At this point, I'd think the profiling you're doing will help narrow that down.  Could be the regex, could be something about that file, could be the finalizer thread doing garbage collection at that point -- hard to say.